# Best way to build a WCF service using given soap message

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need to build a service for given SOAP message below, my client is used this soap message for calling my new WCF service.

I start building wcf `basicHTTPBinding`.

I need to know how to build a service in such a way to guarantee receiving client calls.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ctx:clientContext
      xmlns:ctx="http://ClientContext">
      <ctx:clientUserId>775</ctx:clientUserId>
    </ctx:clientContext>
    <To soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://myserverurl.com/Services/UpdateRequest.svc/soapService</To>
    <Action soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">updateRequestStatus</Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <p20:updateRequestStatus xmlns:p20="http://com.myservice.update.ws">
      <requestId xmlns="">6699</requestId>
      <status xmlns="">Approved</status>
    </p20:updateRequestStatus>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to implement such service and publish it to my client in order to call it. an error occurred when client call my service:

Error Description below:

> The message with Action 'updateRequestStatus' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this case by generating a C# Classes for given WSDL. It will build an Interface for that WSDL using this command: wsdl "wsdl file path" "xsd file path". 
Then based on generated class , I create a WCF service and implement all required methods for my service.

based on this , any client have a soap message as above can consume my service without any conflicts.